# Can we add itemscope & itemtype on <HTML> tag for microdata schema?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

```
<html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ApartmentComplex">
   ---
   ---
   ---
</html>
```

Is it a good practice to add itemscope on `<html>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid doing that unless it was for a WebPage entity or subtype. Scoping the whole document for a type like that would make it hard to add other entities to the page. e.g. BreadcrumbList

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can add any type on the root `<html>` element.

And yeah `@Tony's` view is right that if you may ever in future or anyone else want to add up some more semantic markup and vocabulary, like [BreadcrumbList](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) type which can be linked to [Webpage](https://schema.org/WebPage) type, then `<html>` element would need a parent element which would not be possible in your case, therefore it would not be recommended.

Although there is **another case**, I've'nt practically used it, where `Schema.org` implicitly consider every web page as [Webpage](https://schema.org/WebPage) type(Search Engine's view) and therefore it would be certain to add up any type to the html page or to the root element as you did, without affecting the page's implicit *WebPage type* declaration.

Comment: You may not believe me what I've found, check out this [itemList](https://schema.org/ItemList)'s second example's microdata.
One can add multiple types within a single element. Therefore, what you are trying to do is absolutely correct, the ApartmentComplex type and any other types can be used upon the same element.